# Add new column to table in field 'selector.tpl'?

Tags: templates, custom-templates

The purpose is to modify the template by adding new columns.As you can see in screenshot CIVICRM propose Nom "name", courriel "email",Telephone "phone", Action . So i want to add column "Job" before column Action.
[image]

I've tried to replace this code in field 'selector.tpl'

[image]

by this one

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a profile with the fields you want to display as a column and set the 'Default Contact Search Profile' in Search Preferences (CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Search Preferences.

Comment: this is a great tip. I've tested on the Drupal Demo and it works fine but on our Wordpress instances it's cracked. First row has no header anymore :-/  Except setting 'Search view' for this profile and turning it active, is there anything to define?

Comment: Had a change to try on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: thank you @PradeepNayak

Answer (score 2):

Is this for search results? Instead you could try turning on the built-in extension "Search Kit" and it lets you add columns.

Comment: We just want to improve the basic and advanced searches result template to get a simpler view